# In how many ways? Checking my answers

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

A computer monitor manufacturer produces 7 different models, all with a different selling price.  Suppose that 4 different customers (call them A, B, C and D) will each purchase one of the monitors.

I just want to check my answers. If this is right or wrong.

In how many ways may this be done assuming that no two customers purchase the same model?

I did a sample space here. i assume that no two customers purchase the same model so i did like this . Customer A can purchase 7 different models. B can purchase 6 different models. C can purchase 5 different models. D can purchase 4 different models. Multiply them then i got 840 ways to do it.

In how many ways may this be done assuming that different customers may purchase the same model?

For this one, I got 5040 ways to do it because I 7!.? i honestly i am confuse in this part.

Comment: Same reasoning as before.  First customer has $7$ choices, so does the second, and so on.  Hence $7^4=2401$

Comment: $7!$ is wrong. $A$ can purchase any one of seven models, $B$ can purchase any one of seven models,$C$ can purchase any one of seven models,and $D$ can purchase any one of seven models. So the answer is $7*7*7*7=2401$.

Comment: I really thank you guys for explaining it to me very well!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe you are correct. For those saying it is incorrect, note that Tenji says

> ...assuming no two customers purchase the same model...

Also, the reason you got 5040 is that $7!$ is actually $7*6*5*4*3*2*1$, whereas you wanted $7*6*5*4$.

Comment: actually the part where ...assuming no two customers purchase the same model... is the 7 * 6 * 5 * 4 = 840 ways and actually got that answer before posting here... what i dont get and they answered is the question: In how many ways may this be done assuming that different customers may purchase the same model? they answered 2401

Comment: ah. never mind then. anyway, did the explanation about the factorial error help at all? lol

Comment: They did and it make sense! I also thank you for trying to help me! Combinations and permutations word problems really confuse me.

Comment: :D No problem! They can be quite confusing at first.